# Swift iOS posting file as parameter to PHP Webservice

Tags: swift

I am very new to iOS and swift in general and hope someone can help.  I am trying to create a very simple swift iOS app that will do an HTTP post with multiple parameters one of them being an image or audio file.  Please suggest better approaches if you see one, but this is simply a proof of concept at this point.  Obviously I'm posting so it isn't working from my swift app, but I have been able to get the PHP web service to work via other means (i.e. "Rest Client" ios app).

```
    func uploadFile(filename:String) {
    println("uploading \(filename)")


    var docsDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: docsDir + "/" + filename)



    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.somewebsite.com/testWS.php"))
    var audioData :NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url,options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe,error: nil)

    var bodyData: String = "filenames=Tesing123&userfile=\(audioData)"

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
       {
            (response, data, error) in
           println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    }
}
```

My PHP web service is:

```
<?php

$myparam = $_POST['userfile'];     //getting image Here
$mytextLabel= $_POST['filenames'];   //getting textLabe Here


$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);  

echo basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']);
echo $_POST['userfile'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']) . " has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "!!!!!There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need too look into making a `multipart/form-data` post. See [TUTORIAL: POST TO WEB SERVER API IN SWIFT USING NSURLCONNECTION](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-post-to-web-server-api-in-swift-using-nsurlconnection/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I had same kind of issues time ago.

I recommend you to use some existing lib if you are not expert.

[SwiftHTTP](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP) Should be fine

Otherwise have a look of:

[Agent](https://github.com/hallas/agent)

[Net](https://github.com/nghialv/Net)

(I have had some issues with them as they were not made for multipart/form-data)